# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "" referenced in function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unresolved-external

Im currently getting the following error when I compile my code:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Agent::printSelf(void)" (?printSelf@Agent@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall World::processMouse(int,int,int,int)" (?processMouse@World@@QAEXHHHH@Z)  World.obj

Here is my code

Agent.h:

```
class Agent
{
public:
    Agent();

void printSelf();
```

Agent.cpp:

```
void Agent::printSelf()
{
printf("Agent species=%i\n", species);
for (int i=0;i<mutations.size();i++) {
    cout << mutations[i];
}
}
```

GLView.cpp:

```
void GLView::processMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
if(world->isDebug()) printf("MOUSE EVENT: button=%i state=%i x=%i y=%i\n", button, state, x, y);

if(button==0){
    int wx= (int) ((x-conf::WWIDTH/2)/scalemult-xtranslate);
    int wy= (int) ((y-conf::WHEIGHT/2)/scalemult-ytranslate);

    world->processMouse(button, state, wx, wy);
}

mousex=x; mousey=y;
downb[button]=1-state;
}


void World::processMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
 if (state==0) {        
     float mind=1e10;
     float mini=-1;
     float d;

     for (int i=0;i<agents.size();i++) {
         d= pow(x-agents[i].pos.x,2)+pow(y-agents[i].pos.y,2);
             if (d<mind) {
                 mind=d;
                 mini=i;
             }
         }
     if (mind<1000) {
         //toggle selection of this agent
         for (int i=0;i<agents.size();i++) {
            if(i!=mini) agents[i].selectflag=false;
         }
         agents[mini].selectflag= !agents[mini].selectflag;
         agents[mini].printSelf();
         setControl(false);
     }
 }
```

}

Im pretty stumped. I haven't worked on this code in a long time, so im not sure what has changed to cause this. Anyone see anything wrong?

Comment: Are you compiling and linking the `cpp` file? Is the class definition valid? I don't see any closing brackets.

Comment: Visual Studio is flaky. Sometimes a "rebuild all" will do the trick, because the incremental recompile isn't rebuilding what it should. Make `Agent.cpp` is actually in the project and not just a file in the directory.

Comment: please could you post World::processMouse code?

Comment: I added the correct processMouse method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely cause is that you're not linking in the object created from `Agent.cpp`.

You should check to ensure that it's part of the project and that you're using the correct version, compiled with this current compiler as well (since you state you haven't touched it in a while, it may be that the objects were built with an earlier compiler version, potentially making them incompatible - different name mangling methods, for example).

The first thing to try (once you've established all correct files are in the project) is a full clean-and-build.

On a few other points:

1. The error is occurring in `World::processMouse` meaning that the source for `GLView::processMouse` is probably irrelevant.
2. I find your mixing of `printf` and `cout` slightly ... disturbing. You should probably avoid `printf` for serious C++ programming. It works, but it's mostly intended for legacy C support.

Comment: Clean and rebuild worked to my surprise, as I thought I had already tried it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Observed same issue in Visual studio 2008.
Clean, followed by Rebuild worked for me.